# Does firefox make requests to the history urls on its own?

Tags: firefox, browser, localhost

Strange thing happened: my localhost webserver showed that a browser I was using called some endpoint on it. I'm not sure if it was malware or some strange Firefox behaviour. The endpoint I'm talking about was one from the history of browsing the (localhost) website, but I wasn't browsing the website at the time. I was actually doing nothing, when the new record appeared in webserver log. The browser was opened at the url 'localhost:8080/a.txt'

The script running on the webserver is my very simple Python script serving files. There's no JS on the localhost website. The only way the endpoint was called was some Firefox behaviour e.g. to fetch icon from url (but the endpoint was localhost:8080/someotherfile.txt, not favicon.ico) or I have some malware.

What do you think? What should I do?

PS. Firefox 89.0.2
Xubuntu 20.04